# R apply() format_date

Tags: r, apply

I am a noob trying to troubleshooting an R script written by someone else. The script used to work, but now does not. It is related to `apply()`, which is `apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, ...)`. That says to me that `format_date` is supposed to be a function. But the person who wrote this script did not define a function called `format_date`, and I can't find this function in the libraries that are called in the script. Where do I find `format_date`?

The reason for this line is that the index of this table is date. But we need a date field to export (and not just date as the index), so we are appending it on.

Here is the line throwing the error:

```
result$date = apply(rownames(result), 1, format_date) # add in date to dataframe
```

Here is the error message:

> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: fill
>   Saving 7 x 7 in image
>   Error in apply(rownames(result), 1, format_date) : 
>     object 'format_date' not found

Comment: You can try searching [RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/) for functions in packages. [There's a function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtweet/versions/0.3.7/topics/format_date) named `format_date` in an old version of the rtweet package. If it's a custom function that you no longer have, we can't help you.

Comment: Two other methods of research that work for me: google [`cran format_date`](https://www.google.com/search?q=cran+format_date), often pointing to a full package on the CRAN repo; and using rseek.org, search for the function name [`format_date`](https://rseek.org/?q=format_date). Both often give some good pointers.

Comment: Thanks. I just called the library --> require('retweet'). However, the error says there is no package called retweet. Does that mean the package was recently disabled.Here's the error now --> Loading required package: retweet
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: fill
Saving 7 x 7 in image
Error in apply(rownames(result), 1, format_date) : 
  object 'format_date' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘retweet’

Comment: Another problem: last I checked, `rownames(result)` (assuming a frame or matrix) will return a vector, for which `apply(..., 1, ...)` does not make sense. If you make this question more reproducible (including sample data), we might be able to assist better. Refs for reproducibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Ok, i tried rtweet and exuber. Are you all saying that packages and libraries will often become inactive and therefore I cannot use the function within the library anymore? It was only 2 weeks ago that the script was working. Also, I'm working on that reproducible example.

Comment: "Become inactive" makes sense if you mean "restart R and don't call `library(...)`". When you run `library(exuber)` and `library(rtweet)`, do either one succeed? Does your script now work?

Comment: "no package named ..." means that you have to install it. But note that the function doesn't exist in the latest version of rtweet.

Comment: Thanks! Now it it working, but the file is still writing blank. There is another error I have to figure out. I will try to post something with full code.

Comment: Dear user 332, it looks like you solved this given problem. So you can write an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can comment out or delete line `result$date = apply(rownames(result), 1, format_date)` from your code.

In older version of `rtweet` package the function [`format_date`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtweet/versions/0.3.7/topics/format_date) converted datetime Twitter API format to standard datatime objects. Current version of `rtweet` functions return datetime (like POSIX) objects so there is no need for function like `format_date`.